# Single word for 'How you are found'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm building a search engine for businesses and I'm wondering if there is a single word for 'how you're found'.

The context is that I need a word to describe a group of properties that determine when the business will show in the search results. The best I came up with is 'Exposure' but my girlfriend thinks its too abstracted.

Any help would be super!

Comment: Do you mean: "How do people normally find you?", like with Yellow Pages, Internet etc.?

Comment: *Your visibility is determined by ...* ?

Answer (score 1):

Businesses might refer to their position in search results as their ***rank***, hence [PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank).

Comment: hmm close, I don't think 'rank' is exactly the right word though in the context I have.

Answer (score 1):

try [findability](http://www.wordnik.com/words/findability) and [searchability](http://quotient.net/blog/2012/9/20/findability-vs-searchability-%E2%80%93-what%E2%80%99s-the-difference-and-why-you-should-care/)

> The quality of a particular 
>   object being locatable.

Answer (score 0):

Originally, these were *metadata* that you would write in the html and could be indexed by search engines but Google, for example, no longer uses this data.

You could also call these terms *search keys* or *identifiers*.

Comment: True, though the businesses we are targeting won't know what _metadata_ means. I do like _identifiers_ though.

Answer (score 0):

How about "keywords"?

> Which keywords best describe the product/service your business is offering?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want a phrase that is less technical-sounding. How about "tags" or "labels"?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps: Locator(s); Locatability?

Answer (score 0):

Is "sources" the kind of thing you are after? Such as organic search, PPC ads, inbouind links from other sites...

Answer (score 0):

I have developed several different types of search engines for my company and I use search **weighting**.

Where different categories, words, tags, whatever may have a certain weight that figures into the order of the information that the user would see on the site.

Weighting can be done by user demographics, content related, using a combination (limitless combinations).

Answer (score 0):

Consider "**criteria**."

> [**criterion**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criterion), pl. *criteria*: a standard on which a judgment or decision can be based.